# New column indicating if row is the first instance of the value for the Entity ID in PowerQuery Editor

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I currently have a column that is created using the following DAX formula which indicates if the listed activity is the first one ever for that `Entity ID`:

```
First Time Activity = 

if('Activity Table'[Timestamp]=

CALCULATE(min('Activity Table'[Timestamp]),
    filter('Activity Table',
        'Activity Table'[Entity ID] = earlier('Activity Table'[Entity ID]) && 
        'Activity Table'[Activity Name] = earlier('Activity Table'[Activity Name])
            )
    )

,1,BLANK())
```

[image: Example]

But I need this now to be a column made in PowerQuery instead of DAX. Any help on the PowerQuery formula would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the query editor, you can do the following steps:

1. Group by `ID` and `Activity` taking the min over the `Date` column as its aggregation.
2. Merge that grouped table back onto the original table (matching on `ID` and `Activity` and using left outer join).
3. Expand the min date column.
4. On the merged and expanded table, replace non-nulls in the expanded column with `1`.